# list posts from two categories on a page - plugin not working

Tags: posts, categories

I've installed this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/list-category-posts/

i've tried using the suggested code to list post which are in 2 categories:

```
[catlist id=64+60]
```

but I don't get anything listed :(

if I do

```
[catlist id=64]
```

or

```
[catlist id=60]
```

I see the lists of the things in each category
but i want to show ONLY the things in BOTH categories

I'm using the shortcode on a page
and trying to call a list of other pages (not posts) which have been categorized using the "Post Tags and Categories for Pages" plugin

am I doing something wrong?
or is there any reason why this should not work for pages?

I event tried reverting to the 2014 theme but it still didn't work
:(

any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to WPSE. Third party plugins are off-topic, see [help/on-topic]. Try the support routes available from the plugin developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason this is not working is because you're trying to combine two plugins that don't work well together. Probably the List Category Posts plugin doesn't have support for page categories.

You have two options now, explain what you're trying to do (I don't understand why you can use posts and categories) and maybe we can give you a better solution, or implement code which will return your pages from the categories you want.

Comment: thanks but what you have suggested is the code for all the posts from each of the two categories, which works. But what I want is just the posts which are in both categories. The instructions on the other_notes page say to do what I have done: 
Using more than one category

    Posts from several categories with an AND relationship, posts that belong to all of the listed categories (note this does not show posts from any children of these categories): [catlist id=17+25+2] - [catlist name=sega+nintendo].

Comment: Updated answer, sorry, I missed the part where you said that you're trying to list page categories not posts.

Comment: you're right - it works with posts in a post fine like this: [catlist id=64+60] it's a bummer as I have loads of pages which are already categorised and need listing in a particular way. Many thanks for your help tho George, I marked your answer as correct